# Evaluate limit of indetermination form 0*infinity using l'Hospital Rule

Tags: calculus, limits

I want to evaluate the following limit

$$\lim\limits_{r\to \infty} r^2\exp(-r/2)$$

I think I should use the Hospital rule.

However, I found that indetermination : $$\ 0*\infty $$

How can I use the Hospital rule to find that limit?

Comment: If you re-express as: $$\frac{r^2}{\exp(r/2)}$$Then it is amenable to L'Hospital

Answer (score 2):

The limit is,

\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{r\to \infty} r^2\exp(-r/2)=\lim\limits_{r\to \infty} \frac{r^2}{\exp(r/2)}&=\lim\limits_{r\to \infty}\frac{2r}{\exp(r/2)\frac{1}{2}}\\
&=\lim\limits_{r\to \infty}\frac{2}{\exp(r/2)\frac{1}{4}}\\
&=0
\end{align}

I have applied the chain rule to compute the derivative of $\exp(r/2)$ and the L'Hospital rule twice.